# Unable to access array of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel .i have printed `print_r($data->toArray());` in view it producing following array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [album_name] => asfasfsaf
    [album_release_date] => 2017-02-08
    [album_produced_by] => safasfasfas
    [music_director_name] => fasfasfsafas
    [music_singer_name] => fasfas
    [album_featured_image] => 3.JPG
    [album_description] => sfsa
    [created_at] => 2017-02-08 05:39:10
    [updated_at] => 2017-02-08 05:39:10
    [album_images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [album_id] => 1
                    [album_image_name] => 1486549223.JPG
                    [album_image_description] => 
                    [created_at] => 2017-02-08 10:20:23
                    [updated_at] => 2017-02-08 10:20:23
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [album_id] => 1
                    [album_image_name] => dsgsdds
                    [album_image_description] => sdgsdg
                    [created_at] => 2017-02-14 00:00:00
                    [updated_at] => 2017-02-21 00:00:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [album_id] => 1
                    [album_image_name] => fasf.jpg
                    [album_image_description] => safsaf
                    [created_at] => 2017-02-21 00:00:00
                    [updated_at] => 2017-02-21 00:00:00
                )

        )

)
```

i am trying to printout `album_images` data but its returning empty

```
print_r($data->album_images);
print_r($data['album_images']);
```

if i print  `print_r($data->album_name);` its returning result

both returning empty

Even i have printed in controller before returning to view

```
$data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImages')->first();

echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data->toArray());
  print_r($data->album_images);
```

returning no result
can any one help me where i am doing wrong

**Controller**

```
  $data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImages')->first();
```

**Updated**

```
  Album {#316 ▼
      #table: "albums"
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "album_name" => "asfasfsaf"
        "album_release_date" => "2017-02-08"
        "album_produced_by" => "safasfasfas"
        "music_director_name" => "fasfasfsafas"
        "music_singer_name" => "fasfas"
        "album_featured_image" => "3.JPG"
        "album_description" => "sfsa"
        "created_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
      ]
      #original: array:10 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "album_name" => "asfasfsaf"
        "album_release_date" => "2017-02-08"
        "album_produced_by" => "safasfasfas"
        "music_director_name" => "fasfasfsafas"
        "music_singer_name" => "fasfas"
        "album_featured_image" => "3.JPG"
        "album_description" => "sfsa"
        "created_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
        "updated_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
      ]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "AlbumImages" => Collection {#320 ▼
          #items: array:3 [▼
            0 => AlbumGallery {#324 ▼
              #table: "album_gallerys"
              #connection: null
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:6 [▶]
              #original: array:6 [▼
                "id" => 20
                "album_id" => 1
                "album_image_name" => "1486549223.JPG"
                "album_image_description" => null
                "created_at" => "2017-02-08 10:20:23"
                "updated_at" => "2017-02-08 10:20:23"
              ]
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #events: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => AlbumGallery {#325 ▼
              #table: "album_gallerys"
              #connection: null
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:6 [▼
                "id" => 21
                "album_id" => 1
                "album_image_name" => "dsgsdds"
                "album_image_description" => "sdgsdg"
                "created_at" => "2017-02-14 00:00:00"
                "updated_at" => "2017-02-21 00:00:00"
              ]
              #original: array:6 [▶]
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #events: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            2 => AlbumGallery {#326 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }



**Updated 2**
```

> dd($data->relationship_method());

```
HasMany {#312 ▼
  #foreignKey: "album_gallerys.album_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Builder {#315 ▶}
  #parent: Album {#316 ▼
    #table: "albums"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:10 [▶]
    #original: array:10 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "album_name" => "asfasfsaf"
      "album_release_date" => "2017-02-08"
      "album_produced_by" => "safasfasfas"
      "music_director_name" => "fasfasfsafas"
      "music_singer_name" => "fasfas"
      "album_featured_image" => "3.JPG"
      "album_description" => "sfsa"
      "created_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
      "updated_at" => "2017-02-08 05:39:10"
    ]
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #events: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: array:1 [▶]
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
  #related: AlbumGallery {#298 ▼
    #table: "album_gallerys"
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #events: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you print the array in your view? if `$data` is an array, `print_r($data['album_images']);` should be the correct way to do it.

Comment: perhaps can you show the part of your code which handle that result

Comment: @Jerodev. if i print  print_r($data->album_id); then it will display.only facing problem in print_r($data->album_images);

Comment: this is correct `print_r($data['album_images']);` it might not display the result because `print_r($data->album_images);` stops the programs when it error which it might not reach this code `print_r($data['album_images']);`

Comment: @Beginner  print_r($data['album_images']); only i have printed no use

Comment: @Beginner    $data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImages')->first();

Comment: @iCoders I see try converting that to array `->toArray();`

Comment: @RossWilson.sorry typo error  album_id not its id

Comment: Try using `dd($data)` and show us the output so we can see what type of object this is.

Comment: or `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($data); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: @Jerodev.Updated question.

Comment: try `dd($data->relationship_method());`

Comment: @xhulio.updated question

Comment: @xhulio.that rpoducing relationship data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you first convert `$data` into an array `$data = $data->toArray();` and then try to get the data out of it like so `$data['album-images']`.

Let me out, if that works for you.

Comment: .thanks it works.but i have dobut why its not working if we are accessing directly

Comment: Using stdclass is sometimes a bit tricky, especially when it comes to multi-layer ones. Unless you know exactly what is does, it is better to use an array.

Comment: @Michal.Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this:

In **controller**:

$data=  Album::where('id', $id)->with('AlbumImages')->first();

return View::make('new', compact('data'));

In **view**:

{{print_r($user->album_images)}}

Please try like this and let me know what the result.